# C++ operator= return reference to *this

Tags: c++, return-type

Look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Widet{
public:
    Widet(int val = 0):value(val)
    {

    }

    Widet& operator=(Widet &rhs)
    {
        value = rhs.value;
        return *this;
    }
    int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
private:
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    Widet obj1(1);
    Widet obj2(2);
    Widet obj3(0);
    (obj3 = obj2) = obj1;
    cout << "obj3 = " << obj3.getValue() << endl;
}
```

The code runs successfully and the output is (using VS2008):

[image]

When I let the operator= return a value instead of reference:

```
Widet operator=(Widet &rhs)
{
    value = rhs.value;
    return *this;
}
```

It also runs successfully and the output is :

[image]

My question is :Why the second code runs well?Should not we get a error?

Why it is a good habit to return reference to *this instead of *this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why the second code runs well?Should not we get a error?

Because it's perfectly valid code. It returns a temporary copy of the object, and you're allowed to call member functions (including `operator=()`) on temporary objects, so there is no error.

You would get an error if the object were uncopyable.

> Why it is a good habit to return reference to *this instead of *this?

Because not all objects are copyable, and some objects are expensive to copy. You can take a reference to any object, and references are always cheap to pass around.

Comment: It should be added that if you really want to return a temporary, say from `operator+()`, it should always be `const` to avoid the user from modifying it by mistake (See Meyers, Effective C++, Item 3).

Comment: @trion: No, it shouldn't be `const`, because that prevents you from taking an _rvalue_ reference to it.

Comment: That's not true. Functions always return rvalues, therefore you can take rvalue references to it. Try compiling `const int foo() { return 0; } int &&rr = foo();` and see for yourself.

Comment: @trion: Try compiling `struct t{}; const t foo() {return {};} t &&rr = foo();` and see for yourself. (To be honest, I'm not quite sure why your example appears to work, but it definitely doesn't work for user-defined types in general).

Comment: @trion: As noted by Meyers [here](http://aristeia.com/BookErrata/ec++3e-errata.html); search for "rvalue reference".

Comment: Well, that's interesting. So it looks like there is no reasonable way to prohibit a statement like `t++++`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour trion's example above works for `const int` because `const` is being ignored for non-class return types, so a rvalue reference will actually bound to an `int` and not `const int`. `[expr]/6: If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T,” where T is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.`

Answer (score 3):

Usually, You return a reference so that one can use the `=` operator as an l-value.

Comment: "My question is :Why the second code runs well?Should not we get a error?"

Comment: No, it constructs a copy of *this and returns it by value.

Answer (score 3):

When you don't return a reference, `(obj3 = obj2)` gives a temporary copy of `obj3`. The copy obtains the value from `obj1` and is deleted, while `obje3` is never affected by the second assignment.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the second code runs well?Should not we get a error?

It runs because nonconst member functions can be called on (nonconst) class rvalues as well. The second version of `operator=` returns a nonconst class rvalue, so in effect, you assign to the temporary, leaving the previous value in the `obj3` variable.

Therefore, there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you create a temporary (a copy of Obj3, returned by operator=) and assign Obj1 to it. Then it immediately gets destructed. Obj3 remains the result of first assignment - `Obj3 = Obj2`.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a reference from operator=() enables expressions like:

```
a=b=c;
```

Returning a value may be excessive when you don't need it. It can cause extra copy-constructor/destructor calls. Otherwise, returning a value is perfectly valid C++.
People, please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think returning by value is not that big of an issue in C++11 because of move semantics.

Comment: But ,If I return a value instead of reference, are the following expressions unabled : a=b=c; ???

Comment: @XiaJun, yea, if you return a value then `a=b=c;` is still valid. I was wrong, sorry about that. You just need to be sure you have a const specifier (because temporary objects can be implicitly converted to const references only): `Widet operator=(const Widet &rhs)
`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(obj3 = obj2)
```

can be considered as `obj3operator=(obj2)` //hypothetically.
Since you have passed obj2 as parameter, your operator overload will copy the obj2.value into obj3.value.

`(obj3 = obj2) = obj1;`
After the return of from `operator=`, *obj3*(*this,temporary copy) will be returned.
So the equivalent code becomes `obj3=obj1` which will again invoke `operator=` of `obj3` and will reset value of `obj3.value` to `obj1.value` i.e. `1`.